# Where to install activator

Tags: software-installation, permissions, filesystem

I'm installing Typesafe [Activator](https://www.typesafe.com/products/typesafe-reactive-platform#get-started) and wondering where best to put the files.

According to their documentation, it requires read/write access to the directory it's located in as it creates files for certain runtime operations. As a result, it recommends not installing it to `/opt` or `/usr/local`

I've been looking at the [FHS spec](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) to find a suitable location that meets those requirements, but I'm struggling a little

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why not your desktop folder? You could also just make a folder under `~/` and set its permissions to 777 (`sudo chmod -R ~/yourfolder 777`).

Comment: Ideally looking for a folder I wont likely wont be in an out of (i.e. install it and not have to worry about it accidentally getting deleted or anything). Is it considered bad practice to stick it in `/opt` with 777 permissions?

Comment: That should work. Just don't set `/opt` itself to 777. Only set the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, apologies for leaving this unresolved for so long

I ended up saving it under `bin` in my user directory (so, `~/bin/activator`) and giving the `activator` directory `775` permissions, recursively

I've been using that setup for quite a while with no issues. If someone more knowledgeable doesn't consider that bad practice then I'll mark this as the answer

Answer (score 1):

1. As root, unzip Activator inside `/opt`
2. Still as root, run `cd /opt, ln -s activator-dist-1.3.10 activator` (replace "1.3.10" with the version string you have)
3. Still as root, run `chmod +x /opt/activator/bin/*`

You can then call activator like this:

```
/opt/activator/bin/activator
```